# Importing the latitude and longitude into a geofield

Tags: drupal-7

I am using bizreview as the theme for my Drupal 7 site. I am using the Feeds module to import thousands of records that are in CSV files into the site. I need to use a geofield to store the locations.

For this I created a field 'Coordinates' in my content type, made it a geofield and set the widget type to latitude/longitude. I can add the locations manually and they do show up in the map, but I just can't import the coordinates with Feeds.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an ongoing issue with the geofield/feeds interface (see Drupal issue [here](https://www.drupal.org/node/2534822#comment-10315861)).  I had the same problem but applied the patch in comment #12 from the aforementioned link which worked.

One suggestion: If the current version of geofield is not the same as the one used in the patch, or if you are running WAMP without Cygwin, I would suggest applying the patch manually by following the directions [here](https://www.drupal.org/node/534548), making sure to save a safe backup file in the process.  If you haven't worked with patches before, basically all that you (or the patch command) will do for this particular case is add the following lines of code after line 143 in the ./sites/all/modules/geofield/geofield.feeds.inc file (I am working with geofield version 7.x-2.3):

```
foreach ($field[LANGUAGE_NONE] as $delta => $value) {
    if (!empty($value['lat']) && !empty($value['lon'])) {
      // Build up geom data.
      $field[LANGUAGE_NONE][$delta] = geofield_compute_values($value, 'latlon');
    }
  }
```